# Factoring Trinomials With Python

Tags: python, math

I'm creating a program to factor trinomials but I'm getting a bit confused and mixed up and I can't figure out how to correctly print the output.

example trinomial:

> 2x**2+6x+4 = (1x+2)(2x+2)

So far my code just factors each part of the equation

```
def factortri(x, b, c, e):
    for i in range(x): 
        if i > 0: 
            if x%i == 0: 
                if i > x/i: 
                    pass
                else: 
                   h = "%s, %s"%(i,x/i)
                   print h
    for i in range(e): 
        if i > 0: 
            if e%i == 0: 
                if i > e/i: 
                    pass
                else:
                    s = (e/i)
                    f = "%s,%s"%(i,s)
                    print f
                    if i*x + s*x == c: 
                        print i
                        print x
                        print s
                        print x
    for l in range(b): 
        if l > 0: 
            if b%l == 0: 
                if l > b/l: 
                    pass
                else:
                    r = (b/l)
                    g = "%s, %s"%(l,r) 
                    if (l+i)*(r+s)== c+e:
                        print "yes"
                    if (r+i)*(l+s)== c+e:
                        print "yes"
                    if (r+s)*(l+i)== c+e:
                        print "yes"
                    if (l+s)*(r+i)== c+e:
                        print "yes"

x = input("First Tri Co-ef: ")
b = input("First Tri Exponent: ")
c = input("Middle Tri Co-ef: ")
e = input("Last Trinomial: ")

factortri(x, b, c, e)
```

Is there easier way to do this?

Comment: Can you assume that all the numbers are integers?

Comment: yes when i input im only using integers

Comment: Moreover, how do your trinomials look like? Are they all quadratic polynomials? Only one variable?

Comment: they will always be for example 4x^2+8x+4 they will always have a variable with an exponent a variable then an integer

Comment: Is the highest exponent always 2?

Comment: well would it be harder if they were above 2 i guess i could just use ones that arent above to for the sake of the program

Comment: The solution I posted does only work for quadratic polynomials, i.e. the highest exponent is 2, for higher exponents you would need a numeric algorithm (except for easy cases like `ax^4+bx^2+c`, which is basically the same as a quadratic polynomial).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, all your trinomials are quadratic polynomials with only one variable. I would solve this like this:

First bring the quadratic polynomial `ax^2 + bx + c` to a monic form, `x^2 + px + q`, by dividing it by `a`, then set this polynomial equal to 0 and use the formula `x_{1,2} = -p/2 +/- sqrt((p/2)^2-q)` (more readable version on e.g. Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation#Quadratic_formula) to get the two solutions.

Now your solution is simply `a(x-x1)(x-x2)`, where x1 and x2 are the solutions from the quadratic equation.

I add an example to make this more clear:

If you have an equation `2x^2 + 6x + 4`, you divide this by a=2 and get `x^2 + 3x +2`, now you use the formula mentioned above and get the solutions x1=-2 and x2=-1. Now you put everything together and get `a(x-x1)(x-x2) = 2(x+2)(x+1)`, which is the same as in your example.

Comment: so for example 2x^2+6x+4 would be changed to ax^2 + px + q

Answer (score 1):

How about finding factors using the quadratic formula and then substituting the values back in?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation

NOTE: this method can only be used if the exponents are in an arithmetic progression.
I would have asked you this in a comment, but I have too few points to do so.